# ¿Como importar Maven en intelliji IDEA?

Tags: java, java-ee, intellij-idea

Estoy trabajando un proyecto en java EE y necesito integrar Maven en el IDE para integrar librerías, pero no se como hacerlo, por favor alguien que me pueda ayudar Gracias.

Comment: Ya lograste resolverlo?

Comment: Con intellij solo tienes que abrir el archivo pom.xml y el ide se encarga de importar y crear el proyecto

Comment: Tienes versión community o Ultimate? qué número de versión?

Comment: Tengo la version Ultimate